# Cannot connect to local database, C#

Tags: c#, sql

I've got a problem to connect my website with database. The problem is, if I am trying install my website in IIS on the same machine where database is located, I am receiving error: "Login failed for user". But when I am installing my website on a different machine, connection with database works fine. My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="DBConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=myServer; Intial Catalog=myDataBase; User Id=myUserId; Password=myPassword" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient`" />
```

I have to install webservice on the same location where database is with the same password and login. How correct connection string should look like?

Comment: It looks okay, so step 1, can you open the SQL Express and get to the database on the machine where it failed?

Comment: Check your firewall, if this is a remote server.  Ensure that the port is actually accessible.

Comment: Also, verify that no HOSTS entries or DSN entries are required.

Comment: may be `UserId=myUserId;` instead of `User Id=myUserId;` Also may be need delete last symbol in `providerName` ?

Comment: Also ensure you have downloaded the same SQL version (it shouldn't matter but still...) SQL Server Express Edition 2014 (with Management Tools)

Comment: OK, 1 step forward: i cannot login into database with these password and login using SqlManagement already installed on this server. So here must be a problem..

Comment: I found a solution. I asked my manager for solution, and problem was with datasource. Anyway, thanks for advice!